# C++ semaphores and _popen usage

Tags: windows, c++-cli, ipc, semaphore, popen

I am trying to learn how to use semaphores and _popen. I have two processes.

```
 #include <windows.h>  
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <conio.h>
 #include <string>
 #include <sstream>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <process.h>   
 #include <fstream> 
 #using <System.dll>
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Threading;
using namespace std;
```

Process one :

```
int main (){
FILE   *pPipe;
Semaphore^ _pool = gcnew Semaphore( 1, 1, "pool" );
Semaphore^ _eater = gcnew Semaphore(0, 1, "eater" );
char   psBuffer[128];   
if( (pPipe = _popen( "D:\gen.exe", "rt" )) == NULL )
     exit( 1 );
while(!feof( pPipe )){
        _eater->WaitOne();
        fgets( psBuffer, 128, pPipe ); 
    _pool->Release();
        cout<<psBuffer;
   }
   printf( "\nProcess returned %d\n", _pclose( pPipe ) );
} ;
```

Process two(gen.exe):

```
int i=0;
Semaphore^ crt = nullptr;
crt = Semaphore::OpenExisting( "pool" );  
Semaphore^ eat = nullptr;
eat = Semaphore::OpenExisting( "eater" );                
while(true)
{
   i++;
   crt->WaitOne();
   cout<<i;
   eat->Release();
  }
};
```

They do nothing. The only way to make them do something is to delete `fgets( psBuffer, 128, pPipe );`(and i don't know why it is). I want make them to work normally with semaphores, i tried many times, but no result:( What's wrong with this programs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using fgets, which reads until it finds a newline.  But gen.exe isn't writing a newline.  Change this:

```
cout<<i;
```

to this:

```
cout<<i<<endl;
```

And it works as expected.